# Lightning Web component and Visual force page communication behave differently in browsers and the sending signal from VF to LWC does not work

Tags: visualforce, lightning-web-components, browser, communication

This is my first time to try to build an app having both LWC and VF. Thus I refer below links for exploring:
[Link 1 from SalesforceExchange](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/254803/lightning-web-component-postmessage-to-iframe) 
[Link 2 from Salesforce Developer](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/01/lightning-visualforce-communication.html)

Then I have my **VF Page**:

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false" sidebar="false" applyHtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false" docType="html-5.0" >

    <p>VF Page</p>

    <input id="tempMessage" type="text"/>
    <button onclick="sendToLC()">Send to LC</button>

    <p id="receiveFromLWC">Received Message from LWC</p>
    <script>
        var toSource = **"https://abc--minh.lightning.force.com";**

        function sendToLC() {
                var message = document.getElementById("tempMessage").value;
                window.parent.postMessage(message, toSource);
        }
    </script>

    <script>

        var lexOrigin = **"https://abc--minh.lightning.force.com";**
        window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {

            if (event.origin !== lexOrigin) {
                // Not the expected origin: reject message!
             return;
            }
            else{
                var receivedMessage = document.getElementById("receiveFromLWC");
                receivedMessage.innerHTML = "Received from LWC: " + event.data;
            }
        });

    </script>

</apex:page>
```

**My LWC**: 
HTML:

```
<template>
        <lightning-input type="text" placeholder="Type here to send text to VF Page" onchange={handleInputChange}></lightning-input>
        <lightning-button label="Send to VF" onclick={sendData}></lightning-button>        
        <br>
        <p>Received Message from VF: {messageFromVF}</p>
        <br>
        <br>
        <iframe id="vfFrame" src={vfHost} height="100%" width="100%"> . 
        </iframe>

</template>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement, track} from 'lwc';

export default class TestCommunicationLWC extends LightningElement {

    **vfHost = 'https://abc--minh--c.cs2.visual.force.com/apex/testPage';**
    **origin = 'https://abc--minh--c.cs2.visual.force.com';**

    @track messageFromLWC;
    @track messageFromVF;

    constructor() {
        super();

        this.template.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
            alert("from VF constructor" + event);
            if (event.origin !== origin) {
                // Not the expected origin: Reject the message!
                return;
            }
            else{
                this.messageFromVF = event.data;
            }
            // Handle the message
            alert("from VF constructor" + event.data);
        }, false);
    }

    // adding a callback to see if this works
    connectedCallback(){

        this.template.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
            alert("from VF connnect" + event);
            if (event.origin !== origin) {
                // Not the expected origin: Reject the message!
                return;
            }
            else{
                this.messageFromVF = event.data;
            }
            // Handle the message
            alert("from VF connect" + event.data);
        }, false);
    }

    handleInputChange(event){
        this.messageFromLWC = event.detail.value;
    }

    sendData(){
        this.template.querySelector('iframe').contentWindow.postMessage(this.messageFromLWC, this.origin);
    }
}
```

Metadata

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" fqn="testCommunicationLWC">
    <apiVersion>47.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

But the problem is when I run in Edge, it can send the information from LWC to VF but LWC could not receive the message from VF Page.
In contrast, in Chrome, there is no received information from both ways.

**From Chrome and there is no responses from LWC and VF**
[image: From Chrome and there is no responses from LWC and VF] 
**From Edge and there is only one way communication from LWC to VF**
[image: From Edge and there is only one way communication from LWC to VF] 
Please help to advise why there is a big difference in behavior of Chrome and Edge and the solutions to make LWC and VF to communicates both ways in both Chrome and Edge. Thanks.

**Update the error in Chrome when I load the app.**

```
aura_proddebug.js:214 Error: [LWC error]: The `addEventListener` method in `LightningElement` does not support any options.
<c-test-communication-l-w-c>
    at Object.logError (aura_proddebug.js:210)
    at addShadowRootEventListener (aura_proddebug.js:716)
    at DocumentFragment.value [as addEventListener] (aura_proddebug.js:1362)
    at DocumentFragment.value [as addEventListener] (aura_proddebug.js:6025)
    at Object.value (aura_proddebug.js:13363)
    at new TestCommunicationLWC (modules/c/testCommunicationLWC.js:72)
    at invokeComponentConstructor (aura_proddebug.js:7326)
    at createComponent (aura_proddebug.js:7408)
    at createVM (aura_proddebug.js:8434)
    at Object.createElement (aura_proddebug.js:8938)
```

```
Error: [LWC error]: The `addEventListener` method in `LightningElement` does not support any options.
<c-test-communication-l-w-c>
    at Object.logError (aura_proddebug.js:210)
    at addShadowRootEventListener (aura_proddebug.js:716)
    at DocumentFragment.value [as addEventListener] (aura_proddebug.js:1362)
    at DocumentFragment.value [as addEventListener] (aura_proddebug.js:6025)
    at Object.value (aura_proddebug.js:13363)
    at TestCommunicationLWC.connectedCallback (modules/c/testCommunicationLWC.js:93)
    at callHook (aura_proddebug.js:12853)
    at aura_proddebug.js:7304
    at runWithBoundaryProtection (aura_proddebug.js:8825)
    at invokeComponentCallback (aura_proddebug.js:7301)
```

If I remove the template in "this.template.addEventListener" below code, the error is still the same.

```
 this.template.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
            alert("from VF connnect" + event);
            if (event.origin !== origin) {
                // Not the expected origin: Reject the message!
                return;
            }
            else{
                this.messageFromVF = event.data;
            }
            // Handle the message
            alert("from VF connect" + event.data);
        }, false);
```

However, if I change the function to something like below:

```
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.template.addEventListener('message', this.updateMessage.bind(this));
    }

    updateMessage(){
        alert("We are here");
    }
```

There is no error in Loading page but when I click the button "send to VF", the VF still has not received any information in Chrome.

**Update the error message if I click button "sendtoLC" from VF in Chrome console**

```
testPage?core.apexpages.devmode.url=1:20 Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://abc--minh.lightning.force.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('https://abc--minh--c.cs2.visual.force.com').
```

Comment: In Edge's developer console, do you see any error messages when you perform this operation?

Comment: Thanks @BryanAnderson, Below is the error that I saw when I load the App in Chrome console:  aura_proddebug.js:214 Error: [LWC error]: The `addEventListener` method in `LightningElement` does not support any options.
<c-test-communication-l-w-c>
    at Object.logError (aura_proddebug.js:210)
    at addShadowRootEventListener (aura_proddebug.js:716)
    at DocumentFragment.value [as addEventListener] (aura_proddebug.js:1362)
    at DocumentFragment.value [as addEventListener] (aura_proddebug.js:6025)
      at new TestCommunicationLWC (testCommunicationLWC.js:72)

Comment: Something wrong with my Edge browser too, I could not see the dev console after pressing F12. It just disappeard :(

Comment: Thus I guess the addEvenListener method is not accepted by the JS controller for Chrome browser?

Comment: I think you may just want to use `this.addEventListener` in your LWC controller

Comment: I did try to use this.addEventListener but it still have the error. However, if I change the code ==== this.template.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
            alert("from VF connnect" + event);
            if (event.origin !== origin) {
                // Not the expected origin: Reject the message!
                return;
            }
            else{
                this.messageFromVF = event.data;
            }
            // Handle the message
            alert("from VF connect" + event.data);
        }, false);===================================

Comment: To ========== to  [this.template.addEventListener('message', this.updateMessage.bind(this));  updateMessage(){
        alert("We are here");
    } ]=============== Then there is no error in the console any more. Do you think the "function(event)" is not correct?

Comment: By the way, when I tried the postMessage from VF to LWC, I also had this error "testPage?core.apexpages.devmode.url=1:20 Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://abc--minh.lightning.force.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('https://abc--minh--c.cs2.visual.force.com')".

Comment: Just update to my own questions: - the reason Chrome did not receive communication from LWC to VF is because the debug mode is turned on on the VF Page. As long as I turn that debug mode off, the LWC can send message to VF in Chrome. Regard to the reverse sending message from VF to LWC, I use Aura component code as the middle man for communication.

Comment: you could add this as a answer, your comment saved me literally two three days.